# CUDA 4.2.props and target file is missing (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

I'm trying to get the CUDA 4.2 toolkit to work with Visual Studio 2010 (c++ express edition). I'm running this on Microsoft Windows 64 bit.  I have the SDK, the toolkit and Nsight™ Visual Studio Edition 2.2 currently installed, as well as Visual Studio 2010 (c++ express edition).  I have CUDA fully installed and working properly in itself, yet when I try to open a source project with Visual Studio 2010, I get this error:

> Unable to read the project file "bandwidthTest_vs2010.vcxproj".
>   C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2\
>   C\src\bandwidthTest\bandwidthTest_vs2010.vcxproj(65,5): The
>   imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp
>   \v4.0\BuildCustomization\CUDA 4.2.props" was not found.
>   Confirm that the path in the Import declaration is correct,
>   and that the file exists on disk.

I have tried uninstalling the toolkit and the SDK and reinstalling, and this did not fix the issue.
I think if someone could simply give me the files, then it might work.  However, I am still worried as to why I am having this issue in the first place.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's probably solved, but for the ones who land here:

if you encounter this, most probably CUDA toolkit did not install properly. Simply copy the files from

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\extras\visual_studio_integration\MSBuildExtensions
```

to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a space after `Microsoft.Cpp` in the path you provided. Is that just a formatting error in the question? I'm also curious how the SDK ended up inside `ProgramData`.

Try following the instructions in "Build Customizations for Existing Projects", page 10 in the [Getting Started Guide for Microsoft Windows](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_Getting_Started_Windows.pdf). If that doesn't help, check the rest of the document.

If things still aren't working, try another uninstall that includes uninstalling Visual Studio. Then reinstall first Visual Studio then Nsight.

If you get things working, please add a comment and let us know what helped.

Comment: Apologies responding many months later... but I simply uninstalled the SDK + Visual studios and reinstalled Visual Studios first and then the SDK

Answer (score 1):

**Since this post is old, I will answer generally**

Let's say your error is:

> The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp
> \v4.0\BuildCustomization\CUDA 10.1.props" was not found.

Simply, your system cannot find `CUDA 10.1.props` file.

First, check your cuda version:

```
nvcc --version
```

- If your CUDA version is 10.1 (same as your system is asking for), then go with *@paul-ianas*'s answer.
- If your CUDA version is (say) 10.2, then your system is still looking for old files.
  Solution: open your `.vcxproj` file (shown in the error) and **replace every CUDA 10.1 to CUDA 10.2**. Restart your Visual Studio and build again!

Answer (score 1):

**Resolved**
Blog Post
https://saralasewwandikumarage.blogspot.com/2021/08/how-to-use-gpu-in-your-machine-for.html

copy all files from this path (depends on the path you installed CUDA in)

C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\extras\visual_studio_integration\MSBuildExtensions

to this path:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\BuildCustomizations
https://saralasewwandikumarage.blogspot.com/2021/08/blog-post.html